# Calling a java method in Karate

Tags: karate

I'm trying to call a java method from Karate to upload file to server that performs batch execution.Same java function works fine from SoapUI, however from Karate it's not.
Below is the Karate feature file:

```
Feature: Perform Batch Execution

Background:

* call read('classpath:utils/utils.feature') 

Scenario: Copy the batch file to server

* def FileUpload = Java.type("com.batch.FileUpload")
* print FileUpload.fileUpload("hostip","user","pwd","destPath","srcPath")
```

Called java method uses jsch to transfer file, below is the method:

```
public static void fileUpload(String SFTPHOST, String SFTPUSER, String SFTPPASS, String SFTPWORKINGDIR,
            String FilePath){}
```

I'm using **print** for method call as it is a void method,In the Karate report and logs everything looks fine but file isn't transferred.I'm able to call other general java code(date formatting, random no. etc).Please let me know if anything more needs to be done.

Thanks!

Comment: You’ll have to fix this on your own, take the help of someone good at java if needed. the only help i can offer is this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue